# PHP - Cannot read CLI variables using _SERVER

Tags: php, parameters, server, argv, argc

I am trying to read in the filename when running my php file (in CLI).

Runtime Command: `php phpfile.php filename.csv`

The line of code is as follows:

```
$argv = $_SERVER[argv];
```

I am getting the following error:

> Use of undefined constant argv - assumed 'argv' in
>   /home/holcim/csvimport.php on line 14

I have `register_argv_argc` set to `ON`.

Answer (score 2):

That's because `$_SERVER` doesn't exist for the CLI SAPI, because there is no server at the command line. You just use `$argc` and `$argv` because they're automatically populated.

See [this doc page](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php) for some details about running scripts from CLI.

**EDIT**

Note that `$argv = $_SERVER[argv];` would return the `Use of undefined constant argv - assumed 'argv'` in any SAPI (even for a webserver). It should be `$argv = $_SERVER['argv'];` unless you have `argv` defined as a constant.

Comment: Yup it's actually about the quotes in `['argv']`!

Comment: @AbraCadaver - I like DatePeriods, they're useful... and ellipses are useful too.... it's just normal periods that I tend to skip

Answer (score 0):

$argv and $argc are set automatically when you run your script.

$argc gets you the number of arguments (including the script name), and $argv is an array containing the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the argv array and argc variables. Here's code to start you off. It displays an error if you try to run it in a web browser. If the parameter count is less than 2, then it displays a mini help message and exits. Finally, when at least 1 argument is entered, argument1 will contain the first argument value.

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']){echo "Doesnt work in web mode";exit();}
if ($argc < 2){
    echo "\n\n";
    echo $argv[0]." needs arguments as follows...\n\n";
    echo "argument1 -- does something\n";
    exit();
}
$argument1 = $argv[1];
?>
```